# docker golang API ContainerList fails with TLS

Tags: docker, go

I have dockerd configured with TLS authentication on CoreOS;

Cli `docker images` returns me valid list of images:

```
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
busybox                    latest              c75bebcdd211        3 weeks ago         1.106 MB
```

But trying it in "go" code:

```
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=~/.docker
     images, err := cli.ImageList(context.Background(), types.ImageListOptions{})
```

returns me empty list

Below is my docker configuration:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   d5236f0
 Built:        Tue May 30 23:15:08 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   d5236f0
 Built:        Tue May 30 23:15:08 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Images returns images, you're returning containers? Are you expecting them to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of images but you haven't created any containers yet, therefore `cli.ContainerList()` returns empty list

What you are probably looking for is `cli.ImageList()`

Docs:
https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/engine-api/client#Client.ImageList

Comment: My mistake: i used ImageList but pasted ContainerList by mistake

Answer (score 0):

`export DOCKER_CERT_PATH` may not have worked, you can try specifying the tls certificate path directly:

```golang
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(
        client.WithHost("tcp://1.2.3.4:2375"),
        client.WithTLSClientConfig(
            "/path/to/ca.pem",
            "/path/to/cert.pem",
            "/path/to/key.pem"
            ),
        client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation(),
    )
    fmt.Println(cli.ImageList(ctx, types.ImageListOptions{}))
```